# why the jquery .change event doesn't work as I expect

Tags: javascript, jquery

Here is my problem:

I've got a select tag with two options - "Hello" and "World"

html

```
<select>
<option> Hello </option>
<option> World </option>
</select>
```

**In IE** when you choose an option and and it becomes the selected option the blue highlighting remains until you click somewhere else outside the select tag. (In firefox it's not that way)

SO I wrote a script removes focus from the element when an option has been selected.

script

```
$('select').change(function() {
        $(this).blur();
```

But still one little problem stays: 
if i choose Hello and then gain Hello option - the focus will remain and the blue highlighting. But if I choose hello and then world option -everything works..
I read that For select menus, the change event occurs when an option is selected!!!But why the option has to be different from the previous selected to trigger the change event. I hope you understand my English is not so good

here is js example -please test it in IE
[TEST JSFIDDLE EXAMPLE](http://jsfiddle.net/tNLGk/1/)

Comment: [`The change event is sent to an element when its value changes`](http://api.jquery.com/change/). In the problematic situation you're describing, the value doesn't appear to actually change.

Comment: @Boaz, "The change event is sent to an element when its value changes." I know this is a direct quote from the jQuery documentation but it has so many problems, not least of which is that it would lead you to believe that an event's destination an element. To my mind, this is nonsense; an event *arises at* an element and is sent (by underlying browser code) to any appropriately attached event handlers.

Comment: so do you have a solution? which event i can use so no matter if the option selected is different or the same when something is selected i want to remove the focus from the select element!

Answer (score 1):

If you select the same value, the option hasn't really **changed** has it?

The change event is only triggered if the option changes.

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
$(document).ready(function() {
  $('select').mouseout(function(){$(this).blur();})
});
```

It is kind of a hack, will work, but not recommended as if a user is trying to fill it with keyboard then it might be a bit troublesome

Comment: now it doesn't allow me to choose an option. it's not working properly